# while login mysql workbench it ask ssl

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

**create user 'db_user'@'localhost' identified by 'password';
grant select on db1.* to 'db_user'@'localhost';**

when i am login with "db_user" in workbench

It shows below message,

> "connection parameters are correct 
>   SSL not enabled"

login info:
**hostname :localhost
port:3306
username:db_user
password:password
default schema:db1**

Thanks in advance....

Comment: This is informational, and not an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only a warning that you are using an insecure (no SSL) connection.